Get Records Element: Too many query rows: 50001 - Record-Triggered Flow
I was making a flow to update a custom field "Last Sales Task Date," which pulls the latest task date for a contact so long as it is not created by user 'Marketing Leads.' However, I'm getting emails for the 'Too many query rows: 50001' error on the first get records element.

Record-Triggered Flow:
Object: Task created or updated
Get Records - "Get Contacts"
Object: Contact
Conditions: Id = {!$Record.WhoId}
Store only the first record
Get Records - "Get Latest Sales Task"
Object: Task
Conditions: WhoId = {!Get_Contacts.Id} (contact from "Get Contacts" > Id)
& CreatedById <> User ID for Marketing Leads
Sort descending by ActivityDate and store only the first record
Update Records - "Update Contact's Last Sales Task Date"
Specify conditions to identify records, and set fields individually
Object: Contact
Conditions: Id = {!Get_Contacts.Id} (contact from "Get Contacts" > Id)
Set Values: Last_Sales_Task_Date__c = {!Get_Latest_Sales_Tasks.ActivityDate}

This worked without error when debugging, but overnight I received the error. Again, the errors are all occurring at the first Get Records - "Get Contacts" element, and they are all occurring on contact records that don't seem to have had a new task recorded oddly.
Really appreciate your input!



Is the error occurring when you create a Contact or a Task?

You don't need the Get Contacts element at all, You can use $Record.WhoId directly in the Get Latest Sales Tasks and Update Contact's Last Sales Task Date elements to find the Tasks and Contact respectively.

Thanks for the responses, @apz it's happening when a task is created. Thanks for the tips, I'll try to remove the get contacts element.

@apz
UPDATE: debugging after removing the get records is working well - I activated and will report back if I get any more errors!

I created your exact Flow and got the Performance issue because of the Get Contacts element because you're using the $Record global variable. Maybe the new version would solve your issue.

@apz thanks for all your help, the new version with just the Tasks get records element followed by the update element seems to be holding up! Strange that mine didn't warn me about potential performance issues, usually it does. I'll follow up overnight for an update as well and will post as answer. Thank you again!
